# The Auth component still fetching older value of Session?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am manually modifying some key of Auth session in beforeFilter  of AppController.php by this code

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event){
    //$companyId = $this->Companies->find(.........
    $this->request->session()->write('Auth.User.company_id', $companyId);
}
```

And in various actions of different controller i'm trying to get that stored companyid in session by following way

```
public function add(){
    $companyId = $this->Auth->user('company_id');
    debug($companyId); die;
}
```

When i see the value of `$companyId`, it is showing older value not updated one in beforeFilter method of AppController. However if i refresh the page and donot modify session again i will get updated  `$companyId` value.

So my question is how can i update the value of Auth session data so that i can get updated value with `$this->Auth->user('company_id')` code in different places in same request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session storage used by the authentication component uses a buffering mechanism, ie the value from the session is usually only read once per request (unless it is being deleted/emptied).

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.8/src/Auth/Storage/SessionStorage.php#L81-L83**

So either read the value directly from the session in your controller action, or do not write to the session directly, but to the session storage, something along the lines of

```
$user = $this->Auth->user();
if (is_array($user) && $user) {
    $user['company_id'] = $companyId;
    $this->Auth->setUser($user);
}
```